# "TO Monitor abnormal" with my Anycubic i3 Mega S, what is a TO and what happens when it's abnormal?

Tags: troubleshooting, anycubic-i3-mega

I've been getting into 3D printing last year, when I started to print a coaster yesterday, I ran out of filament. I used the filament option to take out the filament remaining... but when I heated it up, I got, something like,
[image: TO monitor abnormal; OK, from I3 Mega S]

I'm not sure what will happen next. I shut it off as quick as possible, so what is it?

Comment: is this a screenshot or a recreation of the screen? We prefer a photo of the actual screen and would need to know what kind of filament you fed, what temperature it was set to and the exact name of the function you used.

Comment: @Trish I didn't get an actual screenshot so I had to design it, I was "removing" the filament and the filament I was removing was a GizmoDorks PLA 1.75 mm Blue